# How much video can you record on a 64 GB iPhone 12?

Tags: iphone, video, storage, video-editing

I’m considering a phone upgrade, but don’t really need a lot of storage.
Approximately, how much of different resolutions video, can one record onto a 64GB iPhone 12?

How many minutes of video would a gigabyte of HDR Video Recording with “Dolby Vision” contain? How can I research this without knowing the technical specifics of a format I cannot access until I purchase a phone?

I’m not looking for very exact answers, just an approximation of HD video sizes and lengths in the context of the camera tech used in this specific phone.

Comment: AD is not a replacement for Google & friends and works better for specific pratical questions than for general "do my research for me" type of question. Considering your query you might find https://www.lifewire.com/how-much-video-can-iphone-record-2000304 helpful (or a lot of other search results on "How much video can I record on an iPhone") :-)

Comment: The new formats available with the iPhone 12 complicate this. Should every question be answered by search engines? This is hardly sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Camera settings on iPhone 12 shows

- 4K @ 60fps is 440MB per minute.
- 4K @ 30fps is 190MB per minute.

I don’t have an iPhone 12 to know exactly how much space is reserved by iOS but supposing it’s 15 GB that leaves 110 minutes of 4k60 or 257 minutes of 4k30.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the question about iPhone 12? In your answer you are referring to iPhone 11.

Comment: @X_841 Sorry that’s what I meant, I asked a friend for the stats

Comment: Ah, I understand, great! +1

Comment: Thank you, this screenshot is very helpful. Many thanks to you and your friend.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, in iOS's camera settings there's a little summary of the amount of data each minute of video at different resolutions/FPS. You can see this summary of how much space it takes per each minute of video in `Settings`>`Camera`>`Record Video`

This is what is says for my iPhone XS, so it would be different on an iPhone 12 with the latest hardware.

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question, as it is specifically asking for iPhone 12 and since he does not own one, he can't go into settings and look it up!

Comment: Oops, I seemed to have misread the question a bit. But this does give somewhat of a guide depending on which model he/she buys.

Comment: Thank you, this screenshot shows the very differensiert I was curious about, by showing how the 12 with HDR has a different size video to the same resolution, but without HDR. Very helpful.